# M1.x Is Magento updated_at changed on Credit Memo / Refund when using Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()?

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo, refund

> Is Magento updated_at changed on Credit Memo / Refund when using
>   Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()?

We use

> Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()

to find orders that have recently been placed.

Only after an order was shipped it can be returned and credit memoed/refunded.

With the below query would we then also include the credit memo's because updated_at is touched when issuing the credit memo or i this not the case -- and do we need some more magic to inlcude the credit memo orders?

thx

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id', $customer_id)
->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'complete'))
->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', array('from' => $dateStart, 'to' => $dateEnd));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the credit memo is a separate entity, when a credit memo/refund is raised it does update attributes on the order entity. i.e. `base_total_refunded`, `base_shipping_refunded`, etc... (these can be seen in table `sales_flat_order`)

Because of this, the `updated_at` attribute would also be updated.